# customize java script function from particular page when that method is used by many pages

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down like

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">ABC</option>
    <option value="2">DEF</option>
  </select>
```

I have the same select box in more than 10 places in different pages.This is populating through ajax.But when i am calling this from a particular page i need to select `ABC` by `default`.But i don't want in remaining places.

I don't want to write the code again in my page.Is there any possibility for this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You'll have to show us whats special about this one select so it can be targeted. It could be parent elements, some text, anything really, even the URL if the selects are on different pages.

Comment: select box in all pages are same

Comment: Is there any possibility for using some simple condition lik `if(document.body.getAttribute('class') === 'mypage')`

Comment: @sabithpocker i think not possible

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a very generic answer that you'll have to modify for your needs, but if the select and all other markup is the same on all pages, which is very unlikely, you have to check the URL to see if you're on a certain page.

At the bottom of the page, before `</body>`, you can do something like :

```
if ( window.location.href.indexOf('/mysite.html') != -1 ) {

    document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value = '1';

}
```

This will set the default value of the first select on the page to `1`, and show `ABC`, if the URL contains `mysite.html`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pjPL2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another example (with JQuery) taking into account the comment you did about loading your combos with options obtained with ajax: [Try if yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw3Cp/26/)

JQUERY:

```
var options = "<option value=\"\">Select</option><option value=\"1\">ABC</option><option value=\"2\">DEF</option>";

function test() {
    // Populate select with ID destiny 1 without selecting a value
    populate("#destiny1", null, options);
    // Populate select with ID destiny 2, selecting the value of the first index
    populate("#destiny2", 1, options);
}

function populate(destiny, indexOption, options) {
    $(destiny).html(options);
    if (indexOption != null) {
        $(destiny + " option")[indexOption].selected = true; 
        $(destiny).trigger("change");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="destiny1"></select>

<select id="destiny2"></select>

<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="TEST"></input>
```